# Batch file FIND command giving error

Tags: batch-file, find

Following is the FIND command I am using in my Batch program:

```
FIND "Msg" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" > NUL 
if %errorlevel% 0 (
echo "inside if"
"%CUR_DIR%\ErrorCheck.exe" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" "Msg" >>%LOG_FILE%
SET RET_VALUE=1
)
```

The file testoutput.txt contains some numbers and a few records with 0. I am getting the following error on running the FIND command:
0 is unexpected at this time.

Please help how to remove the error.

Comment: no, it is not inside any for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above error. In the below piece of code:

```
FIND "Msg" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" > NUL 
if %errorlevel% 0 (
echo "inside if"
"%CUR_DIR%\ErrorCheck.exe" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" "Msg" >>%LOG_FILE%
SET RET_VALUE=1
)
```

I changed if %errorlevel% 0 to if %errorlevel% NEQ 1, so the code looks like below:

```
FIND "Msg" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" > NUL 
if %errorlevel% NEQ 1 (
echo "inside if"
"%CUR_DIR%\ErrorCheck.exe" "%CUR_DIR%\testoutput.txt" "Msg" >>%LOG_FILE%
SET RET_VALUE=1
)
```